# generate multilevel GUI form in matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

let us consider following picture 
[image]

here is  code for it

```
function varargout = example(varargin)
% EXAMPLE MATLAB code for example.fig
%      EXAMPLE, by itself, creates a new EXAMPLE or raises the existing
%      singleton*.
%
%      H = EXAMPLE returns the handle to a new EXAMPLE or the handle to
%      the existing singleton*.
%
%      EXAMPLE('CALLBACK',hObject,eventData,handles,...) calls the local
%      function named CALLBACK in EXAMPLE.M with the given input arguments.
%
%      EXAMPLE('Property','Value',...) creates a new EXAMPLE or raises the
%      existing singleton*.  Starting from the left, property value pairs are
%      applied to the GUI before example_OpeningFcn gets called.  An
%      unrecognized property name or invalid value makes property application
%      stop.  All inputs are passed to example_OpeningFcn via varargin.
%
%      *See GUI Options on GUIDE's Tools menu.  Choose "GUI allows only one
%      instance to run (singleton)".
%
% See also: GUIDE, GUIDATA, GUIHANDLES

% Edit the above text to modify the response to help example

% Last Modified by GUIDE v2.5 13-Dec-2014 16:02:20

% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @example_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @example_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


% --- Executes just before example is made visible.
function example_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to example (see VARARGIN)

% Choose default command line output for example
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

% UIWAIT makes example wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
% uiwait(handles.figure1);


% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = example_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
% varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Get default command line output from handles structure
varargout{1} = handles.output;


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton2.
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
```

what i need is following : for instance i have created  two program ,one of which will ask user to enter some data and generate signal, and  second one which will plot it or calculates power spectrum, so when i click operation A, it should allows me enter information and generate signal, second one should estimate power spectrum of existing signal, how can i do it? thanks in advance

Comment: And where are you stuck?

Comment: how to connect this main part  to those subprograms

Answer (score 1):

You can write another GUI, e.g. `OperationA`. Then you can call it from `pushbutton1_Callback` in the original GUI. You can also have input\output arguments by using:

```
varargout = OperationA(varargin);
```

Few things to keep in mind:
1. Then entrance point would be at the `OperationA_OpeningFcn`. Do what you need to do with the input arguments in that function (for example, store them in `handles`).
2. You should uncomment `uiwait(handles.figure1);` in `OperationA_OpeningFcn`.
3. Assign any output arguments and close the GUI at `OperationA_OutputFcn`.
4. To get to `OperationA_OutputFcn` use uiresume (for example in a callback of an OK button).

Comment: yes but how to call?do i need finish all those 4 step?

Comment: I wrote how to call. You should start by following all 4 steps.

Comment: i think  i need  real example during these days i will do and will post here,only theoretical it is impossible